# TableLayout within DialogFragment does not respect "wrap_content" attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to draw a TableLayout with 3 TableRows. The table is defined in an xml file (see below) that inflates a DialogFragment. All 3 rows of the table have

```
layout_height = "wrap_content"
```

and the height of each row is computed correctly. However, the enclosing TableLayout contains some big margin and it's not "wrapping" its content as it should. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/borderless_blue_5dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/CHANGE_ROOM"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/web_safe_silver" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="@string/CLIENT"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_regular" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_client_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@drawable/dark_rect_smooth"
                android:textColor="@color/discoveroom_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_regular" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/web_safe_silver" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="@string/ROOM"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/room_number"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@drawable/dark_rect_smooth"
                android:textColor="@color/discoveroom_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_regular" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="@string/CHARGE"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_regular" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/charge"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@drawable/dark_rect_smooth"
                android:textColor="@color/discoveroom_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_regular"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/web_safe_silver" />

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/alternative_rooms_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </ListView>

  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/edit_buttons"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_close"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/CANCEL"
            android:textColor="#894556"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/OK"
            android:textColor="#489456"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: TableLayout in DialogFragment contains big margin around TableRows]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked when I replaced the outer most LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout. 
So, I know how to fix it, but I still don't get why that happened. Additional comments are welcome.

Comment: I also have the same problem. So I replaced root layout with Relative. Now it is working. Thanks for posting the solution dude.